# implement shell sort by ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I try to implement shell sort by ruby.

```
def shell_sort(list)
  d = list.length
  return -1 if d == 0
  (0...list.length).each do |i|
    d = d / 2
    puts "d:#{d}"
    (0...(list.length-d)).each do |j|
      if list[j] >= list[j+d]
         list[j], list[j+d] = list[j+d], list[j]
      end
    end
    puts list.inspect
    break if d == 1
  end
  list
end

puts shell_sort([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]).inspect
```

but the result is incorrect.

```
=>[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

I don't know where going wrong, hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use `list.sort`?

Comment: @floum presumably for practice reasons.

Comment: @floum @Jesse Mu is right, I know how to use `sort` method, just want to practice algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referenced Shell Sort in here : [Shell Sort - Wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort), and from that I have understood your algorithm is wrong. Iteration of gap sequence is alright, I mean you iterate only upto `d/2 == 1`.

But for a gap, let's say 2, you simply iterate from `0` to `list.length-2` and swap every `j` and `j+2` elements if `list[j]` is greater than `list[j+2]`. That isn't even a proper insertion sort, and Shell Sort requires Insertion sorts on gaps. Also Shell Sort requires that after you do an x gap sort, every xth element, starting from anywhere will be sorted (see the example run on the link and you can verify yourself).

A case where it can wrong in a 2 gap sort pass :

```
list = 5,4,3,2,1
j = 0 passed :
list = 3,4,5,2,1
j = 1 passed : 
list = 3,2,5,4,1
j = 2 passed
list = 3,2,1,4,5
```

After it completes, you can see that every 2nd element starting from 0 isn't in a sorted order. I suggest that you learn Insertion Sort first, then understand where and how it is used in Shell Sort, and try again, if you want to do it by yourself.

Anyway, I have written one (save it for later if you want) taking your method as a base, with a lot of comments. Hope you get the idea through this. Also tried to make the outputs clarify the how the algorithm works.

```
def shell_sort(list)
  d = list.length
  return -1 if d == 0

  # You select and iterate over your gap sequence here.
  until d/2 == 0 do
    d = d / 2

    # Now you pick up an index i, and make sure every dth element,
    # starting from i is sorted.
    # i = 0
    # while i < list.length do
    0.step(list.length) do |i|

      # Okay we picked up index i. Now it's just plain insertion sort.
      # Only difference is that we take elements with constant gap, 
      # rather than taking them up serially.
      # igap = i + d
      # while igap < list.length do
      (i+d).step(list.length-1, d) do |igap| 

         # Just like insertion sort, we take up the last most value.
         # So that we can shift values greater than list[igap] to its side,
         # and assign it to a proper position we find for it later.
         temp = list[igap]
         j = igap
         while j >= i do
           break if list[j] >= list[j - d]
           list[j] = list[j-d]
           j -= d
        end
        # Okay this is where it belongs.
        list[j] = temp

        #igap += d
      end

      # i += 1
    end
    puts "#{d} sort done, the list now : "
    puts list.inspect
   end
   list
end

list = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
puts "List before sort : "
puts list.inspect
shell_sort(list)
puts "Sorted list : "
puts list.inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your algorithm needs a little tweaking.

The reason it fails is simply because on the last run (when `d == 1`) the smallest element (`1`) isn't near enough the first element to swap it in in one go.

The easiest way to make it work is to "restart" your inner loop whenever elements switch places. So, a little bit rough solution would be something like

```
(0...(list.length-d)).each do |j|
  if list[j] >= list[j+d]
    list[j], list[j+d] = list[j+d], list[j]
    d *= 2
    break
  end
end
```

This solution is of course far from optimal, but should achieve required results with as little code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should just do a last run on array. To simplify your code I extracted exchange part into standalone fucntion so you could see now where you should do this:

```
def exchange e, list
  (0...(list.length-e)).each do |j|
    if list[j] >= list[j+e]
      list[j], list[j+e] = list[j+e], list[j]
    end
  end
end

def shell_sort(list)
  d = list.length
  return -1 if d == 0
  (0...list.length).each do |i|
    d = d / 2
    puts "d:#{d}"
    exchange(d, list)
    puts list.inspect
    if d == 1
      exchange(d, list)
      break
    end
  end
  list
end

arr = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
p shell_sort(arr)
```

Result:

```
#> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```